# What is the female equivalent phrase to the slang phrase, "big dick energy"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, slang

"Big dick energy" is usually a positive phrase about someone that they have a lot of confidence or energy. According to Urban Dictionary by user neptuneestate (https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=big%20dick%20energy), the definition is the following:

> confidence without cockiness. it is never misplaced and it cannot be simulated. it is the sexual equivalent of writing a check for $10k knowing you got it in the bank account.

Example sentence:

> pete davidson is 6’3 with dark circles, exudes big dick energy , looks evil but apparently is an angel, and loves his girl publicly.

Alternative phrases are "big pp energy" which seems to a cuter version of "big dick energy", sometimes said by girls around 13-25 for fun/for confidence from my experience on YouTube and on friend/dating apps.

**I'm looking for the female-equivalent of the phrase "big dick energy"** What I mean by that is to replace "dick" with possibly a female body part but still used as a phrase that means the same thing.

Comment: The phrase is intended to imply that the qualities that it stands for, exhibited by a male person, are stereotypically masculine. It is not clear whether you are seeking a term that would be suitable for these same, stereotypically masculine qualities, when they are exhibited by a woman, or a term for some stereotypically feminine qualities that would be somehow analogous. Neither would, however, be the 'female equivalent' of this phrase.

Comment: @jsw29 I never really thought about that about different stereotypical qualities for the gender. I think I would want a term that has stereotypical feminine qualities related to confidence that would be analogous, but it doesn’t have to be equivalent, maybe similar enough